# reading from a json file in java

Tags: java, json, json-simple

Hello I have been trying to read a JSON file in java using the json.simple library, I read more than a dozen of tutorials on how to do this but in the end the way my JSON file is written is causing me a lot of trouble.

```
{
"0": {
    "POI": "43df8ad6f964a520b92e1fe3",
    "latitude": 40.731356448341,
    "longitude": -73.988671302795,
    "photos": "https:\/\/irs3.4sqi.net\/img\/general\/612x612\/343235_eezF7KZ55QpdVVNuMTFOO86bikjUbmrxb1IEuf2C1uI.jpg",
    "POI_category_id": "Arts & Entertainment",
    "POI_name": "AMC Loews Village 7"
  },
  "1": {
    "POI": "4bfec352daf9c9b64038f9ef",
    "latitude": 40.75358312925,
    "longitude": -74.214450350548,
    "photos": "https:\/\/irs1.4sqi.net\/img\/general\/540x720\/c5xfqE_ajHOZb1LBtUBEdYNlc9aQ12EoPcavI_dVkDw.jpg",
    "POI_category_id": "Food",
    "POI_name": "Wendy's"
  }
...
}
```

My issue is that I have no idea how I can get the first value "0":, "1": without having a key next to so I could use the `.get("KEY")` function. 
I tried something like `jsobj.get(i)` and then increasing the value of `i` by one every time but that didn't work at all.

This is my first time trying to do something with json so I have no idea if what I am trying to do is right.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: If you're using the `org.json` library for `JSON` representation, you can read the entire file and store the content in a `StringBuilder`, and then use that `StringBuilder.toString()` to instantiate a `new JSONObject(StringBuilder.toString())`.

Comment: "I tried something like jsobj.get(i) and then increasing the value of i by one every time but that didn't work at all." - That should work fine, but remember `i` would need to be a string in this case. Can you include a [mcve] so we can see what's going on?

Comment: org.json.simple is the library i am using @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

Comment: @berry120 out of curiosity i tried that myself literally 2 mins ago and it kind of worked, yet i don't know what would be the best way for me to extract the data :/

Comment: What do you mean by "Kind of worked"?

Comment: Key should be string.

Comment: no it worked fine with that, it just printed the data in a different order. My bad

Comment: Different order like?

Comment: the .get(String.valueOf(i)) is just fine, what would be the best way to go through the data though. Casting it to a JSONArray is not possible from what i read.

Comment: thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is stored in a string called `json`:

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(json);
JSONObject ele;
for(int i=0 ; (ele=(JSONObject)obj.get(Integer.toString(i)))!=null ; i++) {
    System.out.println("Index " + i + ":");
    System.out.println(ele.get("POI"));
    System.out.println(ele.get("latitude"));
    System.out.println(ele.get("longitude"));
    ///etc.
}
```